# chosen-select not working on bootstrap modal

Tags: php, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

i cant make chosen-select to work in a bootstrap modal. i tried to search for a possible solution and have tried to remove other classes/styles that may conflict with chosen-select's css. i also tried the code below:

```
jQuery('body').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                       $(".chosen-select").chosen();
           });
```

but it's still not working. the search field is not even visible. it's just like an ordinary dropdown field. :( what other things should i keep in mind to make it work?

pls. help. thanks in advance for not nagging. :) i really tried my best to search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it!

just added

```
$(".chosen-select").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

and it worked. XD 
 thanks to mr. koala of this post: [Chosen dropdown list not working with Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18152004/chosen-dropdown-list-not-working-with-modal?rq=1)

**cant delete my post so i just added the answer instead.